# Como desactivo en la corrección automática de los comentarios en eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Al momento de programar en Java con el entorno de desarrollo *Eclipse* , cuando introduzco comentarios en mi código, no quiero que se corrija la gramática, porque la corrigió en inglés, y por ese motivo todo lo que escribo en español sale mal, quiero saber cómo inhabilitarlo o al menos que se corrija en español.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ve a las preferencias de Eclipse vía Window / Preferences (o presiona <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> en Mac). En la parte superior izquierda hay una caja de texto. Allí ingresa "Spelling" (sin las comillas). Se aplicará el filtro y aparecerá la opción Spelling en el menú de árbol. Selecciona esa opción y en la ventana izquierda aparecerán las opciones de revisión de texto. Yo recomiendo deshabilitarlo por completo al desmarcar la casilla.

Aquí una muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, me ayudaste mucho!